# How to open trade after 3 candles since last trade was closed?

Tags: if-statement, pine-script, strategy-pattern

I am having trouble with my strategy. It opens and closes trades in the same exact time sometimes. I need the strategy to wait 3 candles before it can close trade, then wait another 3 candles before it opens the next trade.

Appreciate any solutions!
Thanks

I tried using ta.barssince or strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Tray with [strategy.position_size](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_size)

Something like that:

```
if longEntry and strategy.position_size <= 0 and strategy.position_size[1] <= 0 and strategy.position_size[2] <= 0
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, comment = 'Long')
```

Comment: Thanks. I eventually used different approach